# Generate SWIG wrapper class for Java with a CPP GUI program

Tags: java, c++, swig

is it possible to generate JNI wrapper code for Java given that i have programmed a CPP GUI program in visual studio 2013? I am stucked on how to create the SWIG interface file for for GUI, the examples i have seen are using classes and simple code.

```
#include "resource.h"
#include "GUI.h"
const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

// Global Variable
HBITMAP bitmap;
boolean displayLogo = TRUE;

// The DigProc
BOOL CALLBACK DigProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:

        return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wparam))
        {
        case IDOK:
            EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);
            break;
        }
        break;

    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

// The Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };
    char szFileName[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);

    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CAPTURECHANGED:
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);
            break;
        case WM_CREATE:
            bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "SIT.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
        {   
            // Find the current windows size
            if (displayLogo){
                RECT rect;
                int width = 0;
                int height = 0;
                if (GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect))
                {
                    width = rect.right - rect.left;
                    height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
                }

                hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                ClearWindow(hwnd);
                HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
                SelectObject(hMemDC, bitmap);
                int x = (width - 30) / 2 - 300 / 2;
                int y = (height - 60) / 2 - 169 / 2;
                BitBlt(hdc, x, y, 300, 169, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
                DeleteDC(hMemDC);
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            }
            else{
                drawMaze(hwnd, fileName);
            }
        }
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            displayLogo = TRUE;
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case ID_FILE_NEWMAZE:
                    // Open maze from text file
                    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER;
                    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text File (*.txt)\0*.txt\0";
                    ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
                    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
                    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
                    {
                        fileName = ofn.lpstrFile;
                        drawMaze(hwnd, fileName);
                        displayLogo = FALSE;
                    }
                    else{
                        MessageBox(NULL, "Load file unsuccessful!", "ERROR", MB_ICONERROR);
                    }
                    break;
                case ID_PERFECTMAZE_DFS:
                    displayLogo = FALSE;
                    break;
                case ID_PERFECTMAZE_SIMPLEPRIM:
                    displayLogo = FALSE;
                    break;
                case ID_IMPERFECTMAZE_DFS:
                    displayLogo = FALSE;
                    break;
                case ID_EXIT:
                    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case ID_ABOUT:
                    DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hwnd, DigProc);
                    break;
            }
            break;
            // END NEW CODE
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}



int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    wc.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "ICT1009 Maze",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}

// Draw maze
void drawMaze(HWND hwnd, string fileName){
    if (fileName == "")
        MessageBox(NULL, "File not found!", "ERROR", MB_ICONERROR);
    else{
        loadFromTextFile *maze = new loadFromTextFile(fileName);
        if (!maze->isFileLoaded())
            MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to generate maze!\n(File uploaded must be in form of binary!)", "Invalid Maze!", MB_ICONERROR);
        else{
            int cellSize = 5;
            int row = 0, col = 0;
            vector<vector<string>> nodeGrid = maze->getNodeGrid();
            int rowSize = maze->getRows();
            int colSize = maze->getColumns();

            static HBRUSH redBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
            static HBRUSH blackBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
            COLORREF penColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
            HPEN gPen = CreatePen(PS_NULL, 3, penColor);
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;

            //ClearWindow(hwnd);
            hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            SelectObject(hdc, gPen);

            for (row = 0; row < rowSize; row++){
                for (col = 0; col < colSize; col++){
                    RECT rec = { col*cellSize, row*cellSize, (col + 1)*cellSize, (row + 1)*cellSize };
                    if (nodeGrid[row][col] == "1")
                        FillRect(hdc, &rec, blackBrush);
                    else
                        FillRect(hdc, &rec, redBrush);
                }
            }

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
    }
}

void ClearWindow(HWND hwnd)
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd); // Get the windows device context

    RECT rect = { 0 }; // A RECT that will define the "client area" of the window

    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect); // Set "rect" to the client area of the window

    // This will fill the window with all white
    FillRect(hdc, &rect, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));

    // Free Memory
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

}


void SetClientSize(HWND hwnd, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)
{
    if (IsWindow(hwnd))
    {

        DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
        DWORD dwExStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        HMENU menu = GetMenu(hwnd);

        RECT rc = { 0, 0, clientWidth, clientHeight };

        if (!AdjustWindowRectEx(&rc, dwStyle, menu ? TRUE : FALSE, dwExStyle))
            MessageBox(NULL, "AdjustWindowRectEx Failed!", "Error", MB_OK);

        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top,
            SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);
#ifdef _DEBUG   
        RECT newClientRC;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &newClientRC);
        assert((newClientRC.right - newClientRC.left) == clientWidth);
        assert((newClientRC.bottom - newClientRC.top) == clientHeight);
#endif
    }   
}
```